# Javascript datetime parsing from string

Tags: javascript, string, parsing, datetime

I am trying to parse a string to javascript Date object, I tried different ways to parse it to Date but none of them seems to work. Initially I was thinking it will be easy to parse string to Date as JavaScript Date has constructor that takes a string or I would use Date.parse() method but it seems that I was wrong.

Here is string for date format-
**2015-12-01 00:28:28.1271204 +01:00**

What I have tried so far-

```
var dateCalc = new Date(str);
var dateCalc = Date.parse(str);
```

Please this JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/D7c28/12/

Please suggest solution for this. Please let me know if I am missing something.

Thanks :)

Comment: [Have you checked the documentation?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) The `Date.parse()` method only parses the date formats it's designed to parse. If you have a date in another format, you'll have to interpret it with your own code or else defer to a library like Moment.js.

Comment: Thanks @Pointy, I will surely check documentation, I missed that :)

Comment: `var dateCalc = new Date(str);` works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me:

```js
var str = "Fri, 15 Nov 2013 09:00:00 -0600"
var date = new Date(str);

console.log(date.getDate())  // 15
```

`date` is a Date object with many methods like `getDate()`. Check out the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

**Update:**

`2015-12-01 00:28:28.1271204 +01:00` seems not to be a valid date for the default constructor (but works fine in node on my Mac). So I use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) and it works fine.

Check out the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iplus26/D7c28/15/).

Comment: Sorry I changed the str value. You can check actual format in question I have asked. It works for the format you have pointed out.

Comment: @NikhilChavan Check out the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iplus26/D7c28/15/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost sure that

```
var dateString = "2015-12-01 00:28:28.1271204 +01:00";
var dateCalc = new Date(dateString);
```

Will work (dateCalc) will have a proper date (that is, Tue Dec 01 2015 00;28:28 GMT+0100.

If you want to be a more flxeible with the solution you always can try MomentJS which gives you a lot of possibilties with format, localization and such stuff.

Comment: But what are you trying exactly? Because dateCalc will have a proper Date object which has methods like getDate and such.
        dateCalc.getDate()

I quite can't understand why you are using split and pop over there?
Check for example http://jsfiddle.net/n23v7tun/